# Joomla Component _JEXEC

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a joomla component where I want to  add  posts  with Ajax.  In php part of   my Ajax, everithing is workin   , if I write  `defined('_JEXEC', 1);` but  the  component can't  pass  jed checker.   I'v got error  that  `defined('_JEXEC', 1);` lines  is  wrong.  when I  wrote `defined( '_jexec' ) or die( 'restricted access' )`  , the component can pass the  jed checker,  but nothing work in  php.  Can someone help me , please.

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your php. Under `Global Configuration -> Server Settings` set `Error Reporting` to `Maximum`, then try do debug.

Comment: I wrote defined('_JEXEC', 1); An then add defined( '_jexec' ) or die( 'restricted access' ).  Everything is  working )